# Hijacked Malaysian plane position geometry

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangulation

Sorry to get geeky in the midst of a tragedy and likely horrible crime, but does anyone know how they got this diagram showing the possible last known positions of the possibly hijacked Malaysian flight MH370? Looks to me like some variant of the SSA triangle problem, with two solutions. Maybe this would make a good high school geometry topic.

[image]

Comment: Someone pointed out it's probably a simple combination of distance from the marked satellite and a range of possible distances flown based on the time period that ping signals were received combined with high and low speed estimates. Still, a nice question for analysis in a high school classroom, if you can ignore the ugly associated facts.